# split numbers and symbols from normal text

Tags: python, split, numbers, symbols

Hi guys I'm a java developer but I'm a newbie in python, I have this peace of java code I would like to translate in python:

```
    private static String split(String str) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9,+]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]").matcher(str);
        while (match.find()) {
            output.add(match.group());
        }
        String result="";
        for (String s:output){
            result+=s+" ";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

so for example if the input is: "aaaa+1" output become: "aaaa +1".

I have already tried to use:

```
def split(nome):
    r = re.findall('\d+|.\D+', nome)
    #m = r.match(nome)
    print(r)
```

but doesn't take into account the symbol (+).

here other examples:

```
auhsuahsAsaasaA+19090 ---> auhsuahsAsaasaA +19090 
+67433998AAAAAAA ---> +67433998 AAAAAAA
ARENA-89         ---> ARENA -89
```

Can you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: "aaaa+1" output become: "aaaa +1" It's not clear for me!

Comment: I would like to split normal text from symbols and numbers, here other examples:
    auhsuahsAsaasaA+19090 ---> auhsuahsAsaasaA +19090  ;
    +67433998AAAAAAA        ---> +67433998 AAAAAAA    ;

Comment: You've got to put new examples in your question (not in here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this re.findall command which matches all continuous alphabets and the numbers (*with optional - or +*).

```
 re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[+-]?\d+', s)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[+-]?\d+', '"AAAA +2"')
['AAAA', '+2']
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[+-]?\d+', 'auhsuahsAsaasaA+19090')
['auhsuahsAsaasaA', '+19090']
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[+-]?\d+', '"AAAA +2"')
['AAAA', '+2']
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work here the out put of "aaaaa+32"-->['aaaaa', '+', '32']

Comment: Sorry I have replied to fast: if the input is "AAAA +2" the result should remain the same, but with your code the output is "['AAAA', ' +', '2']"

Comment: then use the solution i told you at very first. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Without `re` module

```
def divide(text):
    local_text=list(text)
    for i in range(1, len(local_text)):
        if local_text[i].isspace() or local_text[i-1].isspace():
            continue
        elif local_text[i-1].isalpha() != local_text[i].isalpha():
            local_text[i-1] += ' '
    return ''.join(local_text)

print(divide('auhsuahsAsaasaA+19090 +67433998AAAAAAA ARENA-89'))
...
auhsuahsAsaasaA +19090 +67433998 AAAAAAA ARENA -89
```